# Can I have an Enum reference a text string?

Tags: typescript

I know I can have an Enum like this:

```
enum TShirtSize {
  Small = 3,
  Medium = 5,
  Large = 8
}

var mySize = TShirtSize.Large;
```

But is there any way that I could specify a text string instead of the numbers 3,5 and 8 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a class that you can use for purely string based enums. Demo:

```
class Enum {
    constructor(private value: string) { }
    /** For equality == with string */
    toString() {return this.value }
    /** For send to server serialization */
    toJSON() {return this.value }
}

class Foo extends Enum {    
    static First = new Foo('First')
}

// From server to browser
var recievedDTO: { something: Foo } = <any>{
    something: 'First'
}
console.log(recievedDTO.something == Foo.First); // true

// To server 
var sendDTO = {
    something: Foo.First,
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(sendDTO) == '{"something":"First"}'); // true

// Warning: don't use `===`
console.log(recievedDTO.something === Foo.First); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

No - Strings are not allowed as values for enums which are "subtypes of the Number primitve type".

This is covered in the [TypeScript Language Specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) under a few sections.

> (From 9.1) The enum type *is a distinct subtype of the Number primitive type*.
>
> (From 9.2) The body of an enum declaration defines zero or more enum members which are the named values of the 
>   enum type. *Each enum member has an associated numeric value of the primitive type introduced by the 
>   enum declaration*.
>
> (From 9.2) Expressions specified for computed members must produce values of type Any, *the Number primitive type, or the enum type itself*.

However, note that restriction to integers is at least "advisable",

> (From 9.2) A ConstantEnumMemberSection introduces one or more constant members with *consecutive 
>   integral values starting at the specified constant value*<sup>1</sup>
>
> (From 1.7) Section 9 describes how programmers can also *explicitly assign integers* to enum members..

<sup>1</sup> In the current TypeScript compiler if a non-integral number is specified then the the following members must be assigned a value explicitly; however it *is* allowed to use non-integrals as constants. This follows from the above LS rules that enums are subtype of *number*, not of a more refined "integer".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use the identifier as a string description; you can obtain both the value of the enum, which is an integer, and its name - here is an example:

```
enum TShirtSize {
  Small = 3,
  Medium = 5,
  Large = 8
}

// 8
var sizeValue = TShirtSize.Large;

// "Large"
var sizeName = TShirtSize[sizeValue];
```

You may also want to take a look at the [type-safe enum](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/typesafe-enum-pattern-in-cvb-net/) pattern as this can be useful in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for that:

```
var enumStrings: { [id: TShirtSize] : string; } = {};
enumStrings[TShirtSize.Small] = "Very Small";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` values are stored as `integers`,
I don't think you can store string constants as any of its its value.
However you can use Symbolic constants using `# define`,
for example:

```
> # define small  "any string1"
> # define medium "any string2"
```

and so on..