# TypeScript Enums correct usage of logical or

Tags: typescript, enums

Let's say I have an two enums `Side` and `SideDecider` and in the latter one I have a key `side` which should be a value of `Side` so that when I use `SideDecider.side` I know it is a value of `Side`.

```js
enum Side {
  left,
  right,
}

enum SideDecider {
  random,
  other,
  side, // = Side.left | Side.right is what I would like to use
}

// I am looking for a solution resolving something like the following to true
console.log(Side.left === SideDecider.side || Side.right === SideDecider.side)
// error: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Side.left' and 'SideDecider.side' have no overlap.
```

How would I correctly yield such a usage. Am I trying to incorrectly use `enums`? Thank you for your help in advance.

[Check out example at TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Side%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20left%2C%0D%0A%20%20right%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20SideDecider%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20random%2C%0D%0A%20%20other%2C%0D%0A%20%20side%2C%20%2F%2F%20%3D%20Side.left%20%7C%20Side.right%20is%20what%20I%20would%20like%20to%20use%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20am%20looking%20for%20a%20solution%20resolving%20something%20like%20the%20following%20to%20true%0D%0Aconsole.log(Side.left%20%3D%3D%3D%20SideDecider.side%20%7C%7C%20Side.right%20%3D%3D%3D%20SideDecider.side))

**EDIT**

What I'm actually trying to achieve is the same but using the `enums` as strings so I can use these as keys for objects, see [my second example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgE2FA3gKClANsAZgFygF4oByHA0gGgygCc4BzAC0JNIZf2rQF800oSLETAAIsADGouqlp0AhiAQB7aO0XK1PTCvzNgs9noN0dUAM6jiIpADoKhAD63gdzqygB6L1ACidHQqdABcUADCagAOYPjACFAAbgpYYMAWUAp0yCB6UFGGEHD4cQlwIJkVQtAA7sXMlvgMIIxJKWkJEMAQAEaGFnwCkiogFoRxYwDyPQBWNuiYjmGkFmrA+uWM5h74y6tdGy08-Gg+UACSmdBYKioA1ptQuMGZliqp+HAj9OnviY-7dbMR5YOB3ZD6ZDPLA3OotKD4FRQADaTTSVARdDSAF00MNRu83DdGAAKZHweyOKAAMmprgk0iQdDsViQGIpbh2NLpHIZMhZomxAEoBGdzhlIdlXjUFABPBFIsAWZC8qT81kQpEKSSSdIZcGyjLlBHpfDTGYAfjxI1WOAcKlJEzNs3JogkCDguuZGuFQA). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820171/can-i-have-an-enum-reference-a-text-string), someone recommends using a class for string based enums. Is this best practice?

```js
enum Side {
  left = 'left',
  right = 'right',
}

enum SideDecider {
  random = 'random',
  other = 'other',
  side = Side.left | Side.right // Error: Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members
}

const testObj = {
  left: 'something',
  right: 'something',
}

// (1) I am looking for a solution resolving something like the following to [true, true]
console.log([Side.left && SideDecider.side, Side.right && SideDecider.side])

// (2) Is there a way to use SideDecider.side to access keys in testObj?
console.log(testObj[SideDedicer.side])
```

Comment: `console.log(+Side.left === SideDecider.side || +Side.right === SideDecider.side)` works.

Comment: But then `[+Side.left === SideDecider.side, +Side.right === SideDecider.side]` resolves to `[false, true]` which I would like to resolve to `[true, true]`

Comment: Oh, my bad, I think you are looking for flag enums (which need to be powers of 2). `console.log((Side.left &  SideDecider.side) != 0 || (Side.right | SideDecider.side) !== 0)` https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgE2FA3gKClANsAZgFygF4oBGAGgygCc4BzAC0JICZKBfNNUSWRYACLAAxv2qoq1AIYgEAewiVMc-A2DUlUAM79ifJADocBKAB99wA7Ub40nNAHoHUAJJQp0LHLkBrOCDooXDlxKW05LDB8ODkQGmAtCIA3f0DEiGBVVOw4H2RVZGCsLwB3bPw5KHxqMGA0YVjEnCM5OgAKNvhDY0IAMkwuwRExAx0kAEooAEISAAYzc07+K3omMwshUSRqUf5JmbnxoA

Comment: So when using the SideDecider enum as a key for an Object, I should probably write a function evaluationg these power of 2 enums? I have lots of these use cases so I am really looking forward to doing this a best practices way.

Comment: Not necessarily, numbers are valid keys for an object. You would have been using numbers as keys with regular enums as well, the only difference would have been that that they would have been consecutive numbers

Comment: Thank you. I actually use all enums with `string` representation (and naively thought my simpler example would easily translate) yielding an error when writing `SideDecider.side = Side.left | Side.right`. Would my only option to resolve this be creating a class?

Example: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgE2FA3gKClANsAZgFygF4oByHA0gGgygCc4BzAC0JNIZf2rQF800oSLETAAIsADGouqlp0AhiAQB7aO0XK1PTCvzNgs9noN0dUAM6jiIpADoKhAD63gdzqz4CA9N6gBJKAVoLBUVAGs4EEYoXBVZBUsVLDB8OBUQemALZIA3KJiciGB9Auw4cOR9ZDisUIB3MvwVKHw6MGA0SQycnAcVRgAKAG14e0coADJJ1wlpJDo7KyQqV3cmVimZsfEpGSXRAF0ASiA

Comment: is it a good solution for you?Please check my solution.
[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgE2FA3gKClANsAZgFygF4oAGAGgygCc4BzAC0JIEZKBfNNUSWRYACLAAxv2qoq1AIYgEAe2gkAzJUxz8DYOJIAWVVADO-YnyQA6HASgAfU8DO1G+clDSc0Aeg9QAklCnQWHJyANZwIHRQuHLiUoZyWGD4cHIgNMAGCQBu4ZGZEMAaudhwIcgayNFYQQDuxfhyUPjUYMBowqmZOBZydAAUANrw5paE1rbDgiJiZkZILpMO9ExQAGSrdkKiSNSz-AC6AJRAA)